# How to send Raw Commands to Receipt Printer in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, buffer, escpos

## **What I am Trying to do**

Currently have a receipt printer that supports ESC/P raw printing.

I am building an app that will need to print receipts remotely.

**How I am doing this**

Sending data through PrintNodes API from my app to the printer.

I have used an NPM library 'ESCPOS' and have successfully printed a few samples.

(The **'ESCPOS'** npm is not a remote printing library - but i did the test to make sure everything was working properly and it is)

## **My Issue**

Print node requires that the content-type of your print job to be "raw_base64".

So I take my raw commands

Convert them to hex byte

```
0x1B"@"0x1B0x38'should be bold'
```

and then convert that to base_64

```
MHgxQiJAIjB4MUIweDM4J3Nob3VsZCBiZSBib2xkJw==
```

What I get printed is the plain text of decoded base64 rather than the rendered commands that I sent the printer.

The example receipt above should be the string "Should be bold" in bold.

What i get returned is all the hex values of my raw esc/p commands.

[image: My Print Output]

## **What I've Done**

I have tried ESCPOS (NPM library) and send data directly to the printer without Printnode and it prints perfect.

This leads me to believe that perhaps I am not sending the data correctly.

**This is what I send in my post request to printnode api**

```
let bodytosend = {
    printer: 69079558,  
    title: 'Sample Print Job',
    contentType: 'raw_base64',
    content: "MHgxQiJAIjB4MUIweDM4J3Nob3VsZCBiZSBib2xkJw==",
    source: 'Created from node app.js'
}
```

Comment: why did you convert to hexbyte? have you tried to just convert the binary string directly to base64 and sending that?

Comment: @r3wt i have tried just sending it without converting it. That also gave me the same results

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this repo.

receiptline
Printable digital receipts
Transform markdown-like text to receipt printer commands or SVG images.
https://github.com/receiptline/receiptline